# Alternative hypothesis for learning in brain beyond the hebbian rule

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neurology, neurotransmitter, learning

I was reading on wikipedia that there are [exceptions to the hebbian rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebbian_theory#Exceptions), and I was curious about the possibilities of other hypotheses of how learning occur in the brain. So I would like to know:

> are there alternative (or complementary) hypotheses to the hebbian rule?

Comment: this may be a better fit for the neuroscience stack.

Answer (score -3):

There is Karl Friston's [free energy principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_energy_principle).